# ASP .NET SOAP Service Failing to Deserialize XML for Some Requests

Tags: php, asp.net, soap

I have a ASP .NET SOAP Service that is being called using PHP's SoapClient class. Generally, the service method that I am calling works, but for a select few cases it consistently fails. When it does fail, the service will timeout after about 90 seconds.

I have traced the root cause of the problem to the ASP .NET service where it is attempting to deserialize the provided XML. In the logs, it appears that the .NET service thinks that the XML is truncated:

> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: ns1:Description, [...], SOAP-ENV:Body, SOAP-ENV:Envelope
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 9383)

In my PHP code, I am logging the XML used in the request by calling $client->__getLastRequest(). The XML that is being provided is valid and absent of any abnormal characters that could break the deserialization.

To make matters stranger, it is not only a single request that fails. I can consistently make three requests fail.

Two of the requests are the exact same length and are failing at the same character. The request length of the XML is 9576 characters, the Content-Length header that is posted by PHP is 9615, and the service is failing on character 9383. If I add, remove, or modify anything before the character in question (the letter "d"), the request goes through. The character that is failing is the same letter and in the same spot at both requests.

Although this is true, the third failing request is 4812 characters, has a Content-Length header of 4852, and is failing on character 3863. The character in this case is not the same character (it's the letter "g") and it's not within the same XML node.

If I add anything to these requests or even remove elements from them, they go through fine. I don't have to remove or modify a particular element as long as it occurs prior to the character where the deserialization is failing.

Does anyone have any idea why this timeout could be happening for these requests? Any suggestions for potential workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is - set the Content Length in your POST request to be one character less long than it actually is `length($request)-1`.

Thanks to your detailed description - I have now been able to solve my own problem!